# How to detect a control being invalidated?

Tags: c#, winforms, invalidation

I'm implementing producer/consumer problem. the code looks like this:

```
void producer()
{
  // produce item
  // update some control in form
}

void consumer()
{
  // consume item
  // update some control in form
}
```

producer and consumer methods are executed in different threads from the one that created my form, so I can't update controls in form. I tried following code:

```
void producer()
{
  // produce item
  // put the work to be done in a queue
  this.Invalidate();
}

void consumer()
{
  // consume item
  // put the work to be done in a queue
  this.Invalidate();
}
```

So now I have to detect if the form has been invalidated. I looked in Form's event list, and the best thing I could find was paint event. I put the code that got the job done, and it works fine. The problem is I somehow doubt I've done this the right way although it works. I think paint is not the right place to do the job, as what I'm doing it not just painting. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Edit -- Snippet for Invalidated event handler not working

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.Invalidated += InvalidateEventHandler;
}
void producer(object o)
{
  // produce
  // put work in queue
  this.Invalidate();
}
public void InvalidateEventHandler(object sender, InvalidateEventArgs e)
{
  // Do Stuff to form -- Where exception raises
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invalidate is intended to trigger a Paint.

What you need is to `Control.Invoke()` your own refresh method on he form.

Edit:

Your non-GUI threads should not even call Invalidate(), they can't touch the GUI.

You can write your own ProcessData() form-method and from the Prod/Cons call `mainForm.Invoke(ProcessData)`

Then `ProcessData()` is responsible for thread-safe access to the data and for Invalidating the GUI

Comment: Maybe I don't get it but how does that solve my problem with executing thread not being the creator? Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `new` keyword to make your own implementation of Invalidate

```
    public new void Invalidate()
    {
        // place your logic here
        base.Invalidate();
    }
```

Aslo Form has  [**Invalidated**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidated.aspx) event wich is triggered after Ivalidate ends

**EDIT:**

```
public void InvalidateEventHandler(object sender, InvalidateEventArgs e)
{
    anotherForm.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Do Stuff to form -- Where exception raises
    }));
}
```

Comment: @Stecya ARGH! yes it does have Invalidated event, but it's not displayed in properties window, idk why, I tried it in code and it was shown. But about using my own implementation of Invalidate(), no it won't work, because I'm calling Invalidate with a thread other than the one that created my form, so it would be the one executing Invalidate and I'd have the same problem.

Comment: Then using event is your solution

Comment: Unfortunately, It isn't working, I don't know why. I added a new event handler to Invalidated event, and when it's being executed I get the same error about it being updated from another thread other than the one that created form. :(

Comment: You should use Invoke to interact with other form from differnt thread. See my edit